# ActiveXObject Word (JavaScript) Printing a Word document with an specific printer

Tags: javascript, methods, printing, ms-word, activexobject

actual I want to use an ActiveXObject to print an Word document. But the Problem is the Method from word. I use the method "PrintOut" and want not to set all values of the method (for example the value for the "OutputFileName"). Moreover I want to set an printer with the method.

Here the function I want to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/word.document.printout

Here my code example:

```
var objWord;
objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word Application");
objWord.Visible = true;
objWord.Documents.Open(".........");
objWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(true,false,0,)
```

Thank you a lot for your answers.

Comment: You first need to set the [`ActivePrinter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/word.application.activeprinter)

Comment: Can you show me an code example

Comment: Why don't you check the link in my comment?

Comment: I checked it but I don't no to use it in my code example...

Comment: Because I don't use the Application object.

Comment: So what is `objWord` then?

Comment: Your're right thats working. Thanks a lot. But the other question for the PrintOut Method is it possible to use not all paramter?

Comment: Did you actually read the help article you linked to in your question?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how. For example I only want to set copies to 2. Is that possible?

Comment: Does the help article say that all the parameters are required? Do the code examples show that all the parameters are required?

Comment: No but I don't now how to use in JS

Comment: In your profile you describe yourself as a student. I suggest you do some studying and research, maybe try a few things, and work this last bit out for yourself. The ability to analyze, think through, and solve problems is an essential skill if you want to write code.